# Is that possible to accept more than one answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

Somehow a question have two (or more) answers. Somehow that answers is *similar*, and it's *exactly same*.

So, is that possible to accept more than one answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can accept more that one answer.  Now if there is more that one answer that are excellent, I don't think they can be identical, but if they are I think you should accept the first answer, and then up vote the other answer, but you can't accept both.  My 2 cents.

Comment: So (till now) we can't accept two/more answers. Because one of my question has two identical answers...

Comment: If you have two identical answers then one must be a copy of the other so accept the one that was posted first.  If they are not identical but similar you can up vote both of them and accept either.  If there is really nothing to choose between them accept the answer that was posted first on the basis that they gave you the answer in the shortest time

Comment: @AryoAdhi Just pick whichever you feel is the best one, though the current accepted one has a bunch of things in the comments that could/should be incorporated into the answer.